# unity3D high memory usage in debug

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have a scene in my Unity project with 2 2D skinned and animated character. (and some others things...)

When i build in release, the scene take on pc around 500 MB. (all inclusive)
When i launch debug in unity, Unity take 10 GB more memory... (so my computer is nearly memory empty and crash often...)

If i remove that 2 characters, the memory usage for debugging is more "normal".

Is it normal that just with that 2 characters it take so much memory ?
I have less issue with previous version of unity (i'm using Unity 5.6.1f1)

Comment: That means you have many textures and faces in your mesh, your characters are underoptimized or poorly meshed maybe

Comment: Ten *gigabytes*? Most people don't even have that much ram *installed...*

Comment: I found that it's the Profiler that is using most of the memory... I don't know why the Profiler used all that memory...

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was the profiler that is using that huge memory size.

I remove the profiler recording and memory keep under 1.5G in unity / debug and it's clearly better.

But i don't know why the profiler use so much memory in that scene....